# Get Google Chrome to show all email addresses

Tags: google-chrome

When I log into `gmail` or `superuser`, Google Chrome shows only a single email address and a single line with the text `Chrome Auto-fill settings...`.

[image: Chrome Auto-fill]

How do I get Chrome to just show all entries it knows about? The entry I need can then be selected from the list or irrelevant items deleted.

This is Chrome v50. I recently used v48 on another computer and this works as expected.

Comment: YES. I have this same issue. I have to start typing the other addresses before they will pop up, so what's the point?

Comment: Try the following: click "Chrome Auto-fill settings". In newer versions, i think it might say "Manage". Or, go into settings, find passwords.